# Solr treating numeric as string

Tags: solr

I have a requirement to do a 'contains' query on a numeric field. Are there any suggestions for a good way to do this. e.g. fq=some_tint_field:*7* (out of the box this does not work and returns rather bizarre results - for instance the number 55 is returned as matching *7*)

I cant change the field type from tint because it is used in range queries.
My ideas so far are

- Have a string field myField_str which shadows the numeric field using the copyfield directive and use that for searching instead.
- Investigate about Query Functions and somehow have a custom query mechanism that sort of casts the int to a string before running the query.

Comment: Please share configuration for this.

Comment: is this resolved for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have another field defined...
This another field should be of different field type where it will generate different token which would help you to achieve the contains search.

For example.. You can have a custom field type which will consist ngram tokenizer.

You can add the below field type in your schema.xml.
Use the "partial_search" fieldType for your field(s) where you want to perform the partial search.

Once you are done with schema.xml changes, you need to do the restart the server ans re-index the data.

```
<fieldType name="partial_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```